# Getting list of blocked websites in proxy server

Tags: c#, networking, proxy

I want to have a diagnostic to ensure that my application will not be blocked to access the remote server because of the proxy setting. Is there a way to get the list of a blocked websites in proxy server from the client (.NET)?  I suppose I could use WebRequest and try to call simple echo method in the server and whether I get a 403 or not but wondering if there is other way to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This fully depends on your proxy. There is no standard way to achieve this, but your proxy may implement an interface that allows you to retrieve such information through a management API.